# I have four menu buttons, but only one pop-up window through jQuery, can I generalize or do I need four different windows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I picked up HTML/CSS/Js a few days ago and I made my first very own website. I have this code that is a pop-up:

```
<div class="popupwindow">
    <div class="popupbody">
        <button class="closebtn">X</button>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have a menu with four buttons. The buttons look like so:

```
<ul>
    <li class="menuone"><a href="#">button one</a></li>
    <li class="menutwo"><a href="#">button two</a</li>
    <li class="menuthree"><a href="#">button three</a></li>
    <li class="menufour"><a href="#">button four</a></li>
</ul>
```

Right now my jQuery code only triggers when the button with the tag "menuone" is pressed.

My question is, can I use the same jQuery code somehow and generalize this?

Comment: jQuery code please..

Comment: The jQuery code is the same as here: https://codepen.io/Karlo_112/pen/yVYBVd

Comment: so you want to trigger the jQuery action for all 4 buttons?

Comment: Yes, but with different content. Say button one is for contact, button two is for about us, etc..

Comment: are you using bootstrap framework?

Comment: I am not. I did everything from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery selector for all buttons like following:

```
$('ul li a').on('click', function(){
  // write your code here
})
```

Comment: How can I then have different content under each button?

Comment: Simply you can put 'popupwindow' div inside each li with content as you need. Then when clicking button you can show its corresponding 'popupwindow' otherwise hide. For this you must know about jquery functions. Follow this link: https://api.jquery.com/